# Cannot import a custom component - Angular2 and TypeScript

Tags: typescript, angular, systemjs

I'm trying to import a custom component within my app.ts, but getting the error "*TS2307: Cannot find module 'MyComponent'*" I've looked it over, couldn't find anything that would help me.

Some people wrote: *use "moduleResolution": "classic"*, but if I do that then I get the TS2307 error for everything else (all angular2/...) except MyComponent.

Others wrote "run tsc --declaration MyComponent.ts" - which does generate a MyComponent.d.ts file (while throwing errors in the console, like "Cannot compile unless the --module flag is provided" - which IS provided in tsconfig as an option -  or "Cannot find module 'angular2/common'" for whatever I am importing in MyComponent.ts - but it does generate a .d.ts file), but when trying to compile app.ts it still gives the same TS2307 error. Nohting I've found worked.

This is my project structure:

```
| /app
|     /resources
|         /dev
|             /ts
|                 app.ts
|                 MyComponent.ts
|         /dist
|             /js
|                 app.js          // transcompiled app.ts
|                 MyComponent.js  // transcompiled MyComponent.ts
|             /modules            // files copied from the /node_modules/**/ folders (because node_modules is outside versioning and also outside public root (public root is the /app folder)
|                 es6-shim.js
|                 angular2-polyfills.js
|                 system.src.js
|                 Rx.js
|                 http.dev.js
|                 angular2.dev.js
|     index.html
|
| /node_modules
|     /angular2            // 2.0.0-beta.1
|     /es6-promise         // 3.0.2
|     /es6-shim            // 0.33.3
|     /rxjs                // 5.0.0-beta.0
|     /reflect-metadata    // 0.1.2
|     /systemjs            // 0.19.6
|     /zone.js             // 0.5.10
|
```

This is my **tsconfig.json**:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "ES5",
        "module": "system",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "removeComments": true,
        "noImplicitAny": false,
        "outDir": "app/resources/dist/js"
    },
    "files": [
        "app/resources/dev/ts/app.ts"
    ]
}
```

My **app.ts** :

```
import { bootstrap } from "angular2/platform/browser";
import { Component, View } from "angular2/core";
import { HTTP_PROVIDERS, Http, Response } from "angular2/http";

//My Custom Components:
import { MyComponent } from 'MyComponent';

/**
 * APP
 */
@Component({
    selector: 'my-app'
})
@View({
    directives: [MyComponent],
    template: `
        <my-component></my-component>
        plus other html
    `
})
class MyApp {
    public whatever;

    constructor(public http: Http) {
        // initialize this.whatever
    }

    makeRequest(): void {
        this.http.request('/_http/response.json')
            .subscribe((res:Response) => {
                this.whatever = res.json();
            });
    }
}

bootstrap(MyApp, [ HTTP_PROVIDERS ]);
```

And here's my **MyComponent.ts**:

```
import { Component } from 'angular2/core';
import { NgFor, NgIf } from 'angular2/common';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-component',
    template: `
        <div>MY IMPORTED COMPONENT</div>
    `
})
export class MyComponent {

    constructor() {}

    doSomething(): void {
        console.log('Doing something');
    }
}
```

My *app.ts* and *MyComponent.ts* are both in the same folder. Anyway, I've also tried path like this: import { MyComponent } from "/app/resources/dev/ts/MyComponent".
Also, I've tried adding it to the files array in tsconfig (some people wrote that I should do that)... Still... Nothing worked! I've also checked the js output, because some people wrote that even though it throws the error, it might still be compiled... No luck!

====================

## EDIT:

Ok, as inoabrian suggests in the first comment... I thought I tried everything, but it seems I haven't tried "./MyComponent" for the import part.

```
import { MyComponent } from './MyComponent';
```

Now the transcompiler does it's job. Thank you inoabrian, but now I have another issue. When I try running in the browser, I check my console and both systemjs and angular2-pollyfills scream:

```
http://my-app/resources/dist/js/MyComponent 404 (Not Found)
```

respectively:

```
XHR error (404 Not Found) loading  http://my-app/resources/dist/js/MyComponent(…)
```

Don't be thrown off by the path (when comparing to my project folder structure), I have my local server pointing at /app when I access http://my-app

This is my **index.html** with system config and all included js files:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <!-- ... Meta tags & CSS assets -->

    <script src="resources/dist/modules/es6-shim.js"></script>
    <script src="resources/dist/modules/angular2-polyfills.js"></script>
    <script src="resources/dist/modules/system.src.js"></script>
    <script src="resources/dist/modules/Rx.js"></script>
    <script src="resources/dist/modules/http.dev.js"></script>
    <script src="resources/dist/modules/angular2.dev.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<script>
    System.config({
        packages: {
            app: {
                format: 'register',
                defaultExtension: 'js'
            }
        }
    });
    System.import('resources/dist/js/app.js')
            .then(null, console.error.bind(console));
</script>

<my-app></my-app>

</body>
</html>
```

I have the feeling that I should do one more thing with the transcompiled file "MyComponent.js", but don't know what (I've tried to add it to System.import, hoping it would accept an array... but it seems it doesn't). What should I do next?

**P.S.** This is disappointing nevertheless, I hoped that importing MyComponent into app.ts would be everything, and that I would find the MyComponent class + everything from MyComponent.ts + my transcompiled app.ts file ALL IN ONE app.js file, not haveing yet another js file :(

Comment: Have you changed the import location to './MyComponent'?

Comment: I thought I've tried everything, but it seems I didn't. It worked with "./MyComponent"... but now things raise another issue, I've edited my question and added the issue at the end, after "EDIT:"

Comment: Now this part seems to be a directory issue with your server.
This can occur when you have nested directories for development and dist.
So could you post what your server side code looks like..?

I'm running off of lite-server
and I set my directories to be served via an array 
[
]

Comment: I have a simple apache server (wamp setup on windows) pointing to the /app folder as the "public root". So, when I access `http://my-defined-hostname` it actually points to the /app folder within my project (ofcourse, for this some editing of the windows' hosts file was also necessary). Everything else works just fine, app.js is imported by systemjs... and it is in the same place as MyComponent.js
I also have another setup on nginx, on a virtual machine... made by my colleagues, but it behaves the same

Comment: Do you have a solution yet? I have the same issue.

Comment: @Zhenyang Hua I forgot about this until recently... And I have just been answered on Udemy, by an instructor. Now it seems silly, but here's what the problem was: in the System.config section, I thought that the key "app" from "app: {}" is generic, a convention coming from "application". BUT NO! It seems that it's a PATH... to your app root folder. So, if you have your transpiled/js files in "folderX/blah-blah" then in System.config, instead of app: {} you should have : 'folderX/blah-blah' : {}. I hope you made the same mistake so this will help you.
(continued in the next comment)...

Comment: ... (continued): If you check out the folder structure in my question, I had my index.html IN the APP folder. So, my System.config should've actually been like this: System.config({ packages: { 'resources/dist/js': { format: 'register', defaultExtension: 'js' } } }); System.import('app') .then(null, console.error.bind(console)); The folder "app" didn't even existed as far as index.html was concerned.
And now, if I check even their quickstart, it does explain that "app" si actually a path. But, until I've been told directly what my mistake was, I never noticed that they also explain that :))

Comment: Aha! I do have the same misunderstanding! Thank you!!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I know it's long overdue, but perhaps others might benefit from an answer.
I did realize what the final problem was (other than what I've already edited in the original question). Here it is:
I did mention I had a custom folder structure and wasn't willing to change it. If I had, it would have worked by simply following the angular 2 quickstart. But it wouldn't have made me realize the problem in my specific case and I wouldn't have understood how System.js works.

The problem was in my System.config() - in the packages section.
This is the bad code:

```
System.config({
    packages: {
        app: {
            format: 'register',
            defaultExtension: 'js'
        }
    }
});
System.import('my/path/to/app_main_file');
```

My mistake was thinking that the key "app" is simply a generic key, comming from the word "application". It turns out that in the packages object, each key actually represents a path (where does that package - it's files - reside within your application). So, assuming the folder where my transpiled files are would be "my/app/public" and "app_main_file" is the main js file of my application, then I should've actually had something like this:

```
System.config({
    packages: {
        'my/app/public': {
            format: 'register',
            defaultExtension: 'js'
        }
    }
});
System.import('my/app/public/app_main_file')
    .then(null, console.error.bind(console));
```

Or, you can write the config section even nicer, like this:

```
System.config({
    packages: {
        'my-app': {
            format: 'register',
            defaultExtension: 'js'
        }
    },
    map: {
        'my-app': 'my/app/public'
    }
});
```

I think it's pretty self-explanatory what "map" does and how to use it.

P.S. I know that in my answer I didn't follow the exact same folder structure as in the original question, but I think it makes more sense to explain it like this. If it matters, just replace "my/app/public" above with what I originally had in the question: "resources/dist/js/", and it's the same thing.

Comment: Awesome ! It worked , even I thought app as a keyword .

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are missing the proper parameter in system config.
add it like this:

```
System.config({
   defaultJSExtensions: true
})
```

Comment: Alright, adding this doesn't throw a 404 on MyComponent anymore ('cause now it actually looks for MyComponent.js) - I should have noticed that.
BUT it breaks all the rest. Now I get 404s because it's looking in the wrong places for /angular2/platform/browser.js respectively http.js and core.js (which are not in /angular2 of course - they're actually outside the public root (/app is my public root) - but had no 404s on these before because it wasn't even requesting them before adding defaultJSExtensions: true, and everything worked fine). Why on earth is this happening :| ?

Comment: I would suggest to go through the quick start or the tutorial : https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/quickstart.html and also you should create a plunkr, because this seems to be a neverending story... :) your other files not accessible probably because you are not loading them in index.html. I believe if you check the tutorial it should start working. One more note, that there are some issues with beta1 so I would suggest to use beta0 for now.

Comment: Also, if you have a custom folder structure, it is hard to grab it at first, so I suggest to follow the recommendation on angular page for now.

Answer (score 0):

What is a bit strange is that you don't have a `MyComponent.js` within the same folder than `app.js`. In my case, when I add the `outDir` in the `tsconfig.json` file, all my TypeScript files are compiled into JavaScript in this folder.

Here is my configuration in my `tsconfig.json` file:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES5",
    "module": "system",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "outDir": "app/resources/dist/js"
 },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

I run the compilation phase with the command: `tsc -w`.

Hope it helps you,
Thierry

Comment: It seems I haven't actually tried everything. I tried with "./MyComponent" for the import part in app.ts and it worked, the transcompiler did it's job - it wasn't a transcompiler issue, rather a path issue (don't know how I haven't tried "./" already) and YES, now I do have a MyComponent.js file... but now I have another issue, I've edited my question and added the issue at the end, after "EDIT:"

Comment: In your project screenshot you have the `MyComponent.ts` but not the `MyComponent.js` the browser is looking for, have you compiled it yet?

Comment: The file MyComponent.js is there, I just didn't update the project's folder/file structure in my question. I did it now.